# How do i find the correct xpath for python selenium program, it keeps saying unable to locate?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to get the username box from the twitter log in page, i have followed alot of online tutorials but they all use twitters old log in page, and i am not that good at coding to be able to understand how. I want to locate the username box and send a username to it.

```
import csv
from getpass import getpass
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.twitter.com/login')
driver.maximize_window()


username=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]').send_keys('Username')
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code of username field on twitter is:

```
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" autocorrect="off" inputmode="text" name="username" spellcheck="false" type="text" dir="auto" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu" data-testid="ocfEnterTextTextInput" value="">
```

Observe `name` attribute with value `username`

so, try using this xpath `//*[@name="username"]`

Comment: That didnt work, thank you for trying.

Comment: @Che I have checked the code before posting. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Sorry, im not very good at programming I guess, i edited the post with your answer, and it saying it cant find the element still

Comment: @Che on which browser you are executing your script?

Comment: i have tried chrome and edge so far